# How does the Arduino IDE/build system work?

Tags: arduino, compiler, ide

How does the Arduino IDE/build system work?

I noticed that they use the avr-gcc in the background, 
but what do they do on top?

They seem to have their own "kind of C" language that transforms into something that then compiles by avr-gcc.

Would someone like to spread some light on how it really works?

- What language are they using?
- Are they using something like Make in the background?
- What intermediate files do they create? Can you listcompile a arduino file, or have a look at the generated AVR assambler?

Comment: I think the language *is* C, which is why avr-gcc can compile it.

The setup() and loop() functions are just wrappers for other standard functions, ie loop is actually main()

Comment: Here's something that partially answers your question http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22017/complete-alternatives-to-the-arduino-ide/22019#22019

Comment: @dext0rb actually it's c++

Comment: I think we are both correct. 

"First, the Arduino environment performs some small transformations to make sure that the code is correct C or C++ (two common programming languages)."

From the BuildProcess link below

Comment: @vicatcu Actually it's a subset of C++

Answer (score 4):

This page has everything you're looking for, straight from arduino's website.

https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/latest/sketch-build-process/

Comment: It is preferred to add some detail from the site.  In case the link goes dead in the future the answer will still be somewhat useful.